# Getting error: "Error in table(x0) : object 'PONDICE' not found" while trying to knit

Tags: r, knitr

Apologies if this has been answered already. I tried to find a solution that would help, but I was not lucky. I have several data set which I took from the CD that came with my textbook. When I run my code in R, there are no problems. When I try to knit (word, pdf, and HTML), I get the error message: Quitting from lines 20-26 (hw1math424_3.Rmd)

```
Error in table(x0) : object 'PONDICE' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> tab1 -> table
Execution halted.
```

```
library(epiDisplay)

tab1(PONDICE$icetype, sort.group = "decreasing", cum.percent = TRUE)
```

This produces a nice bar graph in R, but wont knit. I have all the files saved to a desktop folder. Please Help! These files came from Regression Analysis (7th edition) Please ask if you need more info!

Comment: This often means that when testing the blocks within the r-markdown document, they are using variables found in your current R instance/environment. Are you confident that you have defined `PONDICE` *within* the r-markdown itself?

Comment: No I have not, how would I define a .Rdata file in my workspace?

Comment: Your current workspace is not involved (automatically). If you have a `*.Rda` file you need available (in part or whole), you need to explicitly `load(...)` it in the r-markdown document itself. (This means you need good paths, too.)

Comment: Said differently: if your `PONDICE` is currently loaded in your working environment from an `Rda` file, then however you load it into your console is the way you load it from within your Rmd file, it just needs to be done. (I often have a `{r setup,echo=FALSE,include=FALSE}` as one of my first Rmd blocks for handling miscellany like this. Whether to `echo=` and `include=` is a preference best informed by the target audience of the Rmarkdown report.)

Comment: How do I know if my paths are good?

Comment: It's all about absolute-versus-relative paths. You know it's "good enough" if it works. If you have it wrong, things should fail (with something like "file not found").

Comment: Another note about this document: the necessity of an external file (CSV, Rdata, etc) means the `.Rmd` file itself is not sufficient for true reproducibility. This is not necessarily a problem, but realize that if you pass the `.Rmd` file to a colleague without that `.Rda` file (or if you did not get the paths right), you will quickly see errors.

Comment: OK thanks everyone! I used load("file location") and its knitting now! YAY